# Trigger happy Edit Suggestion approvals - what can we do?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-abuse

I have just seen an approval for a Suggested Edit that takes the cake, and makes me wonder exactly how much attention some people are paying to what they do.

In [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/781960) the editor changed the word `auction` to `action`. As far as I can see this edit was incorrect, however by the time I rejected it and typed an explanatory rejection message it had been approved.

So we have at least two people who don't pay attention to what they are approving. What can we do to stop this sort of thing happening? Note that this is not the most egregious example I've seen, but enough is enough - crap edit approvals don't make the site a better place (I've rolled back this edit).

Comment: This applies to all the review queues. I saw [needless self-promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12815797) (10k+ on SO only) upvoted in the late answer queue today, for example. Upvoted twice.

Comment: They are all going for gold with the least amount of work...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree. The question is: has the review process been made too easy? Is it just a new set of badges that people can game? Should the rep level required for reviewing be raised? (Note raising the rep level won't necessarily fix the problem, it just means less people to do bad reviews).